# Run following command even if previous command fails to run?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I have shortcut map in gVim like `nmap <a-k> SomeKeySequence:SomeCommand`, it seems the last command will not be run if the previous key sequence aborted (like no valid operating target then bell rings), is there a way to let the last command to run even if failure happens in previous operations?

Comment: Would you please add a specific example of a command you're trying to run and where it's failing to the question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends a little on what exactly you want to do. You can always call a function and handle errors in the function gracefully (e.g. try/catch clauses).

Alternatively, you can wrap your normal mode command into a :exe ":norm" clause, which will not make the mapping abort on erros, e.g. you could do something like this:

```
nnoremap <f5> :exe ":norm! h"<cr>:echo "done"<cr>
```

(That is a silly example, but shows, that the echo will also shown, if the cursor is at the start of a line and a left movement is not possible).

Comment: This works for me. I am wondering why it works.